# Array of Strings issue

Tags: c

I am currently having difficulty reading words separated by spaces line by line from `stdin`. I am trying to read words line by line, and just print them, from accessing an array of strings.

If I am trying to read this sentence:

`Enter words:
 Hi there, how was your day sir?`

Then I just want to print the sentence underneath, like this:

`Your sentence:
Hi there, how was your day sir?`

This is what my code is so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *word = NULL;
    char **words = NULL;
    int word_size = 1, word_len = 0, word_count = 0;
    int words_size = 1, i, ch;

    word = (char*)malloc(word_size *sizeof(char));

    words = (char **) malloc(words_size*sizeof(char*));

    printf("Enter words:\n");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            word_size++;
            word = realloc(word, word_size+1);
            word[word_len++] = ch;
            word[word_len] = '\0';
        }

        if (isspace(ch)) {
            words_size++;
            words = realloc(words, words_size+1);

            words[word_count] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);

            words[word_count++] = word;
            word_len = 0;
            word_size = 1;
        }

        if (ch == '\n') {

            printf("Your sentence is:\n");
            for (i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
                printf("%s ", words[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            word_len = 0;
            word_size = 1;
            words_size = 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am just not sure why this doesn't work, and why it prints the last word. I know there is a lot of mallocing and reallocing, I am just trying to get better at using them.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Don't cast return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You should use `fgets` to store the whole sentence and then compute it.

Comment: To find where your code goes wrong, use a debugger. It's a really useful tools to find but _but_ also to learn (which is your main goal here).

Comment: probably this solve: `words[word_count++] = word;` --> `strcpy(words[word_count++], word);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are failing assigning the word to your char **.

Using

```
words[word_count++] = word;
```

You are assigning address of local variable word to pointer `words[word_count]`
That gave you, at the end of computation, all words with last stored word into `word` c-string.

You prepare space for the word c-string using

```
words[word_count] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
```

So what you have to do is to copy the content of word c-string into allocaded space

```
strcpy(words[word_count++], word);
```

Otherwise you are leaking memory allocated for the word.

Side notes:

1. `malloc` and `realloc` can fail, so check its return value `!= NULL`
2. You must `free` `malloc`ated memory. On "hi-level" OS memory is freed automatically at the end of execution, but is not granted on all platforms/OS

**EDIT**

Another problem is that you are reallocating the wrong size for your char**
You shoud use

```
words_size++;
words = realloc(words, sizeof(*words)*words_size);
```

That is size of `char *` for the new number of words to store

You can also avoid to use `strlen`, you have the length of word stored into `word_len` variable

```
words[word_count] = malloc(word_len+1);
```

Last thing, before to store a new word you should check that at least alpha char was found. This avoid the output of first space char of your test sting:

```
if ((isspace(ch)) && (word_size>1))
```

Comment: @You're welcome. I updated my answer with another issue.

Comment: You have the word counter, `word_count`. So when it exceed the required number you can skip all other chars until `\n`

Comment: If you are talking about a different implementation then the posted one with `realloc`, and using an array of pointers, you can simply check `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` to retrieve the number of element. So you can check that your word counter is `<`.

Comment: Too much ;) 20 years more or less.